# Regex test with parentheses

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have code like this:

```
  var value = "Mary Jane (Asistant)";
  var regex = new RegExp(value);
  regex.test("Some String to Test");
```

I want to test my regex.It works when I have closed parentheses.But when I test for example value of "Mary Jane (Asistant" it throws error.

Invalid regular expression: /Mary Jane (Asistant/: Unterminated group.

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: You yourself mention the solution: close the group. Unless you want to match literal parentheses. Then you must escape the literal string to be used as part of a regex pattern.

Comment: You need escape metacharcters like `()` with a `\ `

Comment: try `\(` instead of just `(`

Comment: I suggest you test your regex on a live preview site like regex101.com where you get detailed error messages https://regex101.com/r/4YoBIe/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var value = "Mary Jane \\(Asistant\\)";
var regex = new RegExp(value);

console.log(regex.test("Some String to Test"));
console.log(regex.test("Mary Jane (Asistant)"));
```

or this

```js
var value = /Mary Jane \(Asistant\)/;
var regex = new RegExp(value);

console.log(regex.test("Some String to Test"));
console.log(regex.test("Mary Jane (Asistant)"));
```

remember that `value` contains regular expression pattern and some characters like parenthesis `(` and `)` has special meaning and need to be escaped like in snippets above.